# gui demo error about op3 Gazebo

Tags: ros, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing about gazebo of op3
But i enter " roslaunch op3_gui_demo op3_demo.launch " , then, there is an error " RLException: [op3_demo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [op3_gui_demo] nor is [op3_gui_demo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file "

I' d like to know about reason of error.

What can I do for escape from the error?

In advance, roscore and roslaunch op3_manager op3_gazebo.launch were executed.
And i'm using ros noetic (20.04).

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394132/gui-demo-error-about-op3-gazebo/) by [1](https://answers.ros.org/users/93365/1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, the Robotis OP3 simulation is not available for ROS Noetic, last available was for ROS Kinetic: https://index.ros.org/r/robotis_op3/github-ROBOTIS-GIT-ROBOTIS-OP3/#kinetic

To make it work, in ROS Noetic, you will need to build it from source: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/ROBOTIS-OP3 but expect some issues to resolve.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0